Determine the total number of subsets of the set $\{1,2,3,...,2000\}$ such that the sum of the elements in each subset is a prime number.
A few weeks ago, I watched an incredible video by 3Blue1Brown that presented a surprising and elegant solution to finding the number of subsets of the set $\{1,2,...,2000\}$ where the sum of the elements is divisible by $5$. The answer was so clever and unexpected that I couldn’t imagine coming up with it on my own.
Later, I stumbled upon a variation of this problem on Reddit, where the challenge was instead to find the number of subsets with a sum that is a prime number—essentially the opposite condition. The Reddit user suggested that this problem could be approached with a method similar to 3Blue1Brown’s solution. Despite my best efforts, I haven’t made any progress, so I’m reaching out here on StackExchange for help from the brilliant minds who might be able to shed light on this intriguing puzzle.

... and what if you have multiple solutions?

How is that opposite?

@Henriksupportsthecommunity The question in the 3Blue1Brown channel asks for subsets such that the sum of the elements is divisible by a certain integer.  (Though the video specifically talked about 5, the solution works for any integer) And this variation of the problem asks for subsets such that the sum of the elements are not divisible by any integer other than itself and 1.

There are 149002 primes below 1 + 2 + ... + 2000 = 2001000. It looks like a 'dynamic programming' type problem where you would build a 2D array C(i,j) of about 4 billion values (1 <= i <= 2000, 1 <= j <= 2001000), then add up the appropriate elements.

For those who are wondering which video the OP is referring to: Olympiad level counting (Generating functions)

Relevant sequence in the OEIS: A127542

I get a 601 digit number 8304892715152426936070137498180366...127825638179177. My simple Python program took 40 mins to find it.

More generally, suppose we have a set of n consecutive numbers, $A_n$ = {1,...,n}, and want to find the total number of subsets of $A_n$ that add up to a number in a given set S. Firstly, since  the sum of all numbers in $A_n$ is n(n+1)/2, then we can ignore elements of S larger than that. If we construct a (one based) array $C_n$[s] for s = 1 to n(n+1)/2 inclusive of the number of subsets of $A_n$ that add up to s, then the final answer we want is just $\sum_{s \in S} C_n$[s].
We know that $C_1$ = {1}, and for i > 1 we can calculate
$C_i$[s] = $C_{i-1}$[s] + $C_{i-1}$[s-i] + (i == s)
where (i == s) means 1 when i and s are equal, 0 otherwise. Assume indexes less than 1 evaluate to zero. This is the magic formula that allows the end result to be calculated efficiently. It is true because the subsets of $A_i$ that add up to s either contain i or don't. Those that don't are included in the count $C_{i-1}$[s]. Those that do contain i either are i alone or i and a subset sum of s-i of elements less than i.
Only $C_{i-1}$ is required to calculate $C_i$, so the space requirement is of the order O($n^2$) (preferably arbitrary precision) integers. There are O($n^3$) integer additions. Applying this method allowed me to calculate the 601 digit number below representing the number of subsets of $A_{2000}$ which sum to a prime number in about 40 minutes with an old laptop and a simple unoptimised python program.
83048927151524269360701374981803669513231235913384
57648721906297038206398756692872049939952182387776
76280018388524845950129078656467221035401777355142
48480469270450086160790568255606488984684204226218
46146793963340643941518503008500235293658542807207
32719159363109832938753220908931312078063502994344
24312341750457262922746533090414805303868268680748
66076060116609031902385565926623884348992521276793
72661189018667081787420848762404123744333078215363
98997866162579260611267506930919064905326399481766
92797958350410415027075011620429258616974629063357
332305654228520374355076798057182569127825638179177
